# Trimming get_next_posts_link in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `get_next_posts_link()` for custom paging controls in a Wordpress theme. The problem is, the function returns HTML tags and some description text:

```
<a href="http://localhost/awebsite/page/2/" >Next Page &raquo;</a>"><span>Next</span>
```

All I am interested in is the URL. Is there a core function for taking just the URL? Or will I have to perform a bunch of string functions to trim down the stuff I'm returned?

Comment: You would have thought that there would have been some sort of function `get_next_posts_page_link` to do this.

Comment: Ah, I see. I struggled to find it. If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. *edit* Actually, it doesn't do exactly what I'd like. It doesn't test if there are more posts to display.

Comment: There is a [wp_link_pages function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages), that may be what you want

Comment: @JezenThomas I don't think `get_next_posts_page_link` is a documented function, but it seems to need you to pass in the last page number (and no I don't know how to get that...)

Comment: @Neil Looks like I can do it like this: `$next = (get_next_posts_link()) ? get_next_posts_page_link(): null;`. Could you create an answer like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_next_posts_link()` uses an undocumented function `get_next_posts_page_link()` to return the actual URL, so assuming that the next page exists, you could perhaps use that rather than trying to extract the URL from the return of `get_next_posts_link()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use below function for next and previous URL instead of get_next_posts_link() and get_prev_posts_link

```
$next_link = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false));          
$prev_link = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true));
```

Comment: This answer actually does not solve the initial question. Getting the next posts URL, not the next post url. Difference being plural. The answer from Neil's is therefore the better answer to the question.